# Dynamic host in ActionMailer is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have dynamic host in my rails app and according to that I am sending my mails I am using actionmailer and in views I want to link some links.

notification_mailer.rb

```
class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer

def new(email)
   @url = root_url
   mail(to: email, subject: 'XYZ')
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'visit', @url %>
```

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :mailer_set_url_options

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
```

I gave whatever is needed but still getting error telling no host found. And I am calling notification mailer from sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the request when calling the mailer action.

```
class Your_MailerClass < ActionMailer::Base
  def your_mailer_action(request)
    Your_MailerClass.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah thats what I did at the end but its bad hack no :/

Comment: But its not correct answer I am looking for something more sensible which can be run from worker also or background worker.